# Show Post based on taxonomies choosen by the user

Tags: php, wordpress, user-input, taxonomy, webarchive

I have a website with a taxonomy called “db_themen” with different values. The posts from from my webiste are assigned to these taxonomy values from “db_themen”.

On my website, a user can choose in his frontend user profile which “db_themen” he is interested in and save this input. This works through an ACF field of the type “Taxonomy” (field name: “meine_themen”), which is linked to the taxonomy “db_themen”.

According to his input, only posts that are assigned to the same taxonomies are supposed to show on the frontend archives (Elementor archives Loop Grid) for this user.

I tried to code something within my functions.php, but I am a total beginner. The only thing this code does is hide all posts entries in the backend:

```
function abfrage_meine_themen($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_user_logged_in()) {
    $ausgewaehlte_themen = get_field('meine_themen', 'user_' . get_current_user_id());
        if ($ausgewaehlte_themen) {         
            $tax_query = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'db_themen',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $ausgewaehlte_themen,
                ),
            );
            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'abfrage_meine_themen');
```

Can someone please tell me where my mistakes are? I am sure there are several

Comment: It is a really bad practice to use any languages but English in variable names

Answer (score 0):

```
function abfrage_meine_themen($query) {
    // Check if this is the main query and the user is logged in
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_user_logged_in()) {
        
        // Get the selected topics for the current user
        $ausgewaehlte_themen = get_field('meine_themen', 'user_' . get_current_user_id());
        
        // Check if topics are selected
        if ($ausgewaehlte_themen) {
            // Convert the selected topics into an array
            $ausgewaehlte_themen = explode(',', $ausgewaehlte_themen);

            // Setup the tax query
            $tax_query = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'db_themen',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $ausgewaehlte_themen,
                ),
            );

            // Set the tax query to the main query
            $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
        }
    }
}

// Hook the function into pre_get_posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'abfrage_meine_themen');
```

Comment: The ACF field may store the selected topics as a comma-separated string. We use explode to convert this string into an array.Before applying the tax query, it's a good idea to check if there are any selected topics.The tax query is set only if there are selected topics. This prevents modifying the query when no topics are chosen, which might be causing issues.Make sure your ACF field meine_themen is set up to return the term's slug and that it contains valid taxonomy terms.

Comment: i can update answer with details